# NFC support on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, nfc, ios11

iOS 11 brings finally CoreNFC so app developers can support NFC in their apps. Does the iOS 11 support reading the tags by default? Something like QR support in camera app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in support for default NDEF tags such as the NDEF URL tag. For now you need to implement that yourself in your own app using CoreNFC until Apple integrates it on the OS level, e.g., in Apple Wallet.

The way I understand CoreNFC it is much like iBeacons. You basically have a dedicated app that can read dedicated tags and then trigger dedicated actions, e.g., you "scan" an artefact in a museum and the app tells you something about it.

Answer (score 0):

Although nice iOS finally added NFC support, there is no API to transmit apdu commands. So that means you can't communicate with any Desfire tags, Mifare classic, etc unless those cards were previously configured for NDEF.

Another issue I find is that it doesn't support continuous polling. User must activate a "session" (e.g. Click a button) and once a tag has been read, the session is invalidated requiring a user to actively start another session.

A system ui view is always shown when a session is initiated which covers about 50% of the screen.